# HttpClient posting form to a web page returns the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a page on a site designed for adding a certain entity. What I'm trying to do is to add this entity using C# HttpClient. My sequence of steps looks like this:

First I'm authenticate using the client:

```cs
public static async Task<CookieCollection> WebPortalLogin(string baseURI, string phoneNo, string pin)
    {

        var cookies = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookieContainer = cookies
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("page","login"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("noStaticBox",""),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",phoneNo),                
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("password",pin),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("login","Увійти"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("_reqNo","0"),
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURI, content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        var stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var cookieJar = cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(baseURI));
        return cookieJar;
    }
```

Then I send POST request to edit page with all data I want to save:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddCar(string baseURI, string phoneNo, CookieCollection cookieJar, string carNo, string owner)
    {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer });

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("carNo",carNo),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("userName",owner),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("page","carNumbers"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("submit","Додати"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("operation","addCar"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("_reqNo","0")
        });
        cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(baseURI), cookieJar);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURI, content);
        var stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return response;
    }
```

However, this POST request does nothing, and in response I have this very edit page, although when I add this entity in normal way (via web site), I get empty response and entity is successfully saved. Already checked cookies - they're all right. The only thing I can think of is request headers, but successful POST has only regular  ones, like Accept, Accept-Encoding etc. What are my possible mistakes and how can I get it posted? Note: all connections use HTTPS.

Comment: To help debugging, download a product like Fiddler and compare the requests.  I'm sure something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after messing a couple of hours I've discovered that the problem is in one of request parameters and not related to httpclient